# Collaborate BOX folder based on DS group

Tags: java, spring-boot, box, collaboration, boxsdk

So we want to collaborate BOX folders based on DS group (group email).
This group email would be entered from the UI application. The backend creates few folders and needs to add all people in the group as collaborators.

One way would be to list out all people in a group and then add them. Suppose the group members change, this would need synching, etc.

Is there a way directly we can share the box folders to DS groups. Any help is really appreciated

Using BOX SDK on java spring boot application.